# is there a kind of raspberry ADK board

Tags: android, usb, raspberry-pi, adk

Is there a way for a raspberry-pi to comunicate (read/write) to an android device through usb cable and gpio connector, not necessarily usb protocol but with an Api and without root right.

Comment: Using USB cables and connectors for GPIO sounds like a very bad idea.  Why would you want to?

Comment: to make comunicate both without the network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ADK2](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/adk2.html) shown at Google IO in 2012 allows an Android phone to connect and communicate with a USB host. Raspberry Pi can be a USB host so it may be possible to make this work.

The only thing to watch is the phone will most likely go into charge mode and draw the full 500mA allowed by the USB spec. Your Raspberry Pi will need to be able to supply that much power (and power for itself).